# How to Add VS2010 Project to Google Code SVN using AnkhSVN?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, addition, ankhsvn, google-code

Hi I need to add the source files in my following project to Google Code SVN. 
http://code.google.com/p/tnliveplaya/

I have installed AnkhSVN in visual studio 2010 and tried the "Add Solution to Subversion" but i dont have a clue on what to specify as the repo URL etc or any other necessary steps as this is my first time using Subversion or a subversion client. I referred the Google Code getting started guide too but that didnt help.

Please help if you know how to add a VS2010 solution to google code via AnkhSVN. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subversion is pretty straight forward.  You may  want to read up on [svn repository layout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.maint.html#svn.branchmerge.maint.layout)

Your repository has been set up with a solid layout with `branches`, `tags`, and a `trunk` directories.

1. Add your project to the `trunk` using this for your repository URL:
   `http://tnliveplaya.googlecode.com/svn/trunk`
2. Profide your google code credentials.
3. Then you'll be shown a list of files that will be added. AnkhSVN is pretty smart at automatically ignoring files that shouldn't be checked in including items that change every build (e.g. obj and bin directories) or personal user settings (e.g. files ending with .user).
4. You can safely accept the defaults, changing them later if you wish. Read about `svn:ignore`.

It may take a while to commit if your project is large, but you should be good.

Comment: Thanks I also found my firewall was blocking devenv.exe from connecting to code.google.com so all checkins were being blocked giving me the false impression that the AnkhSVN plugin wasnt working. And I had to use https instead of http. So the URL i used which worked for me was httpS://tnliveplaya.googlecode.com/svn/trunk. Maybe this will help someone else too.